# How to get array value not index form input with array options in Cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have faced a problem. I have a form and form field name `card_number`. `card_number` comes from database. Entry Card Number that denotes `card_number` filed. In my ctp file I have written this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Entry Card Number </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('card_number', array('options' => $readCard,'class'=>'form-control','div'=>false,'label'=>false));?>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[image: Entry Card Number]

I have written this code in my Controller. And my view looks like above image.

```
public function add_card_to_device($btsId = null){
    $readerData = $this->CardManagement->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions'    =>  array('site_name'=>$site_name),
            'fields'        =>  array('card_number'),
            'keyField'      => 'card_number',
            'valueField'    => 'card_number'    
        )
    );
    debug($readerData);
    $this->set('readCard', $readerData);
    if ($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put')) {
        $dataa          =   $this->request->data;
        print_r($dataa);
    }
}
```

The problem is occurred when I click submit button. When I click the submit button I get these value. I get the id value instead of card_number **[card_number] => 5a13b3d9-67ac-4847-b3f9-1870991894ac**

```
Array ( [CardManagement] => Array ( [id] => 5a12d321-a7e0-4cf6-ab84-1870991894ac [site_name] => 1235 [card_number] => 5a13b3d9-67ac-4847-b3f9-1870991894ac ) )
```

But my desired output looks like this. **[card_number] => 6473088**

```
Array ( [CardManagement] => Array ( [id] => 5a12d321-a7e0-4cf6-ab84-1870991894ac [site_name] => 1235 [card_number] => 6473088 ) )
```

Any solution or suggestion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cakephp 3.x

When calling list you can configure the fields used for the key and value with the keyField and valueField options respectively:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

```
    $readerData = $this->CardManagement->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions'    =>  array('site_name'=>$site_name),
            'fields'        =>  array('card_number'),
            'keyField'      => 'card_number',
            'valueField'    => 'card_number'
        )
    );
```

> Cakephp 2.x

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

```
    $readerData = $this->CardManagement->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('site_name' => $site_name),
            'fields' => array('card_number','card_number'),
        )
    );
```

Comment: I have change my Controller but output is same. Have any change in view??

Comment: No you don't have to try to debug the $readerData like this debug($readerData);. What is the output?

Comment: After `debug($readerData);` I get this `array(
 '5a12d321-a7e0-4cf6-ab84-1870991894ac' => '3369515',
 '5a13b3d9-67ac-4847-b3f9-1870991894ac' => '6473088'
)`

Comment: As I run the same on my local machine it's working fine. Can you update the question with the latest code

Comment: I have updated my controller. I am using Cakephp 2.7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159464/discussion-between-a-a-noman-and-aman-rawat).